# How to change response.getbody().asstring() back to Response type?

Tags: java, api

I am doing some actions on a Response body after changing it to String:

```
Response myResponse = get(Some Endpoint);
String res = getIncidentResponse.getBody().asString();
//Some operations on the String
```

How to change back this "res" String to Response ?

Comment: You would have to parse it. How exactly you do that depends on what `Response` is.

Comment: If you are not doing any change, why dont use the original response "myResponse"?

Comment: I am getting a JsonPathException exception because of NaN values in the response. I have to replace them with null to proceed.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the conversion of **String to Object**.

```
ObjectMapper objm = new ObjectMapper();
Response response = objm.readValue(string, Response.class);
```

This should work!